Plottable Customize Bars
Given this dataframe:
import pandas as pd    
df = pd.DataFrame({'Grade':[2,3,4,5], 'start':[0,0,20,10], 'end':[100,90,80,100]})
    
       Grade  start  end
    0      2      0  100
    1      3      0   90
    2      4     20   80
    3      5     10  100

I would like to generate a table with it via plottable library with 2 columns: Grade and a column called "Progress" with bars (though a green arrow would be amazing) that starts at 'start' and ends at 'end' where the x-axis starts at 0 and ends at 100. Both 'start' and 'end should be annotated.
Here's an example of what I'm looking for in that column:

If "Start" starts beyond 0, then the bar (or arrow) should start at that relativel position on the "x-axis". The annotations should alwasy be on the left and right sides fo the bars (arrows), as in the example above.
From the "docs", I did find this example for bar charts:
ColumnDefinition(
            "D",
            width=1.25,
            plot_fn=bar,
            plot_kw={
                "cmap": cmap,
                "plot_bg_bar": True,
                "annotate": True,
                "height": 0.5,
                "lw": 0.5,
                "formatter": decimal_to_percent,
                "xlim":[low, high],
            },
        ),

...but I cannot find any reference to control the annotations in terms of labels and positions. I found that I can add "xlim" to the plot_kws but now I need to get start and end from the passed dataframe to determine those values per row.


import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

grades = '2 3 4 5'.split()
starts = [0,0,20,10]
ends = [100,90,80,100]

fig, ax= plt.subplots(layout='constrained')
ax.axis('off')
t = plt.table(
  cellText=list(zip(grades, ['']*4)),
  colLabels=['Grade', 'Progress'],
  colWidths=[0.2, 0.3],
  cellLoc='center',
  loc='center',
  edges='',
  )

# apparently this is necessary to have the cells initialized
fig.canvas.draw()

trax = ax.transAxes
for row in range(1, 5):
    cell = t[row, 1]
    plt.plot((c._x0, c._x0+c._width), (c._y0+0.01, c._y0+0.01),
             lw=0.3, color='black', transform=trax)
    startx = c._x0+c._width*starts[row-1]/100
    dx = c._width*(ends[row-1]-starts[row-1])/100
    plt.arrow(startx, c._y0+0.0225, dx, 0.0,
    color='forestgreen', width=0.006,
    length_includes_head=True,  transform=trax)
plt.show()


Thanks! I ended up just using fig.text for the headings (so they remained in place despite different heights or numbers of rows) and ax.text for each cell, as well as ax.add_patch(FancyArrowPatch(...)) for the arrows.
